# Why they are using full-sized ports on devices?

Tags: usability, mobile, user-behavior

On mobile devices we have micro-usb ports on some ultrabooks we have mini-HDMI or mini display ports. I have a questin, why TV makers or motherboard manufacturers still puts full sized USB ports and full sized video ports like full HDMI. Are they more stable to voltage changes etc? I don't think the answer is the "general usage" we need full sized HDMIs and adapters forvmini sized HDMIs because our most TVs still have full sized HDMI ports instead of mini ones, what is the selection criterias for port sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not for technical reasons.

• First, it's not like you *need* to miniaturize those ports.  Larger connectors are generally easier to handle and more durable.

• Second, compatibility.  With the notable exception of Mini DisplayPort, the full-sized versions of connectors usually enjoy broader support than the mini versions.

• Third, with some connection protocols the size of the connector is semantically important.  Traditional USB (prior to USB-C) is probably the best example of this.  The device with the type A connector (the big rectangular one) is usually the device with more capability and power.  The device with the smaller type B connector (both the squarish one and the newer mini- and micro-B) is usually the smaller, more mobile but less powerful device.  It's all the same USB standard, but the different size of the connectors has come to mean something beyond just the size.  Putting a mini or micro connector on a TV or computer would lead users to think that they are less powerful or capable. For example, consider these examples:

> Hmm.  My TV has a small USB connector, so I guess I can connect my computer to it.  What would I gain from that?

as opposed to

> Hey, my TV has a USB port!

Comment: I got it but I think we are thinking that "smaller connectors should be on less powerful devices" because we rarely see small connectors on powerful devices. I asked that question because I got a Windows CE device that needs a USB type-A (male) to type-A (male) cable on its dock to transfer data. I've got my answer, it is not technical. Thanks for the answer.